# regular expression validate if 5th or 6th character "_"

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am facing the problem in asp.net regular expression.

I need to validate if 5th or 6th character is `"-"` .

for example

`3000-4567, 3000-4568` this string is , separated and also has a hyphen. I just need to check if each comma separated string has 5th or 6th character as a `"-"`.

Current regular expression used in the system is 
`^((\s*\d{4,4}\s*[,]){1,3}?)?(\s*\d{4,4})*$`

currently its validating  `3000,4567`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made two slight changes to your regex:

```
'^((\s*\d{4,5}\s*[/-]){1,3}?)?(\s*\d{4,4})*$'
```

Changed the cardinality of the first numeric group to `{4,5}` to allow for 5 digits numbers (which I guess is what you want since the dash can be the sixth character) and changed the separator to a dash. Notice the slash to escape it, since in square brackets the dash is a special character (tho' you probably don't need the brackets there).

As an alternative, consider `split`ting the string on instances of `-` and then validating the splitted chunks. That should be much easier.